# Unable to extract certain values from list and nested lists in JSON data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, python-requests

From the JSON data at URL: https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers I am trying to the names of drinks whose ‘method’ requires `mash_temp >=65` Celsius and duration to `mash >=75`.

For example:

```
{'mash_temp': [{'temp': {'value': 65, 'unit': 'celsius'}, 'duration': 75}],
 'fermentation': {'temp': {'value': 10, 'unit': 'celsius'}}, 'twist': None}
```

My code is given below:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers'
content = requests.get(url).content
j = json.loads(content)
print(j)
for each in filter(lambda data: data["mash_temp"] >= "65", j):
    print(each["name"],each["mash_temp"])
```

It prints the whole list and nested lists available, but I am unable to get the name of the drinks requires `mash_temp >=65` Celsius and duration to `mash >=75`.

Also,for the ‘ingredient’ of type ‘hop’, need to find all the id, name of the drink, name of the hop, amount of the hop (with unit) and the attribute of the hop.

Comment: `mash_temp` appears to be a list, so of course `some_list >= "65"`  doesn't make much sense (also `65 != "65"`). Why is `mash_temp` a list? Can there be more than one? If so, what results do you expect? If you only want the first value, you need to ask for it: `data["mash_temp"][0]['temp']['value']`.

Comment: @Mark , I am trying to find the name of the drinks where mash_temp >=65 Celsius and duration to mash >=75

Comment: I understand that @paul. The data you presented, however, leaves the possibility that there may be more than one mash_temp —`data['mash_temp']` is a list of things. Your example only has one thing in that list, but it's not clear if there could be more than one.

Answer (score 1):

Hey buddy you have to study the dataset more to know how it is structured before you will be able to retrieve information, write code that accesses those inner lists a step at a time, improving readability and make your life easier during debugging. (simple over complex)

```
# retrieve information from url
url = 'https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers'
content = requests.get(url).content
j = json.loads(content)

# Going into the dataset a step at a time
for data in j:
    # retrieve the method
    method = data['method']
    
    # retrieve the mash_temp information from the method
    # note the mash_temp is saved in a list
    mash_temp = method['mesh_temp][0]
    
    # not all temp or duration contain values, some of them
    # are None values, this is a catch all try statement
    # you can write a more defined try/except statement
    try:
        if mash_temp['temp']['value'] >= 65 and mash_temp['duration'] >= 75:
            print(data['name'], '---', mash_temp)
    except:
        # define what to do here if anything temp or duration
        # contains None values
        pass
```